# To count the number of occurrences of first field in text file

Tags: bash, command, sort, uniq, msys

i require to count the number of occurrences of first field in txt file and to print output file as two column file having first field of input file & no. of occurrences of fist field in input file

Comment: Please edit the question and add some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ count[$1]++ } END { for (field in count) print field, count[field] }' file.txt
```

That is, use the first field as the key in the associative array `count`.  For each record, increment the value corresponding to the field.  At the end, loop through the keys of `count` and print them and the associated values.